# Weird dialog when proposing a tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I received the privelege to suggest tag synonyms today, so I thought I'd have a poke around and see how to use it.  When suggesting a synonym I got this mysterious dialog:

[image]

What does the error message mean in this context?  My best guess is there was a false positive, with some sort of detection of the "3d" as being a version number, but even that seems a bit out of whack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are over careful with version numbers.

In the past people synonymized all sorts of *wrong* synonyms like [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) `->` [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and so on.

It is common to mistake a tag synonym with a tag hierarchy. The intention with synonyms is to catch cases where two tags are exactly the same thing like [c-sharp](/questions/tagged/c-sharp) `->` [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). We use the synonyms to enforce consistency.

When analysing the *mistakes* people made I discovered that if a number is involved, *in any way*, on either side of a synonym a moderator should get involved.

Take your specific case:

[matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) encompasses [mplot3d](/questions/tagged/mplot3d) see: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/index.html

However, [mplot3d](/questions/tagged/mplot3d) contains no `2d` functions that are contained in the parent library [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib)

The synonym you are trying to suggest is, in fact, wrong. The system is doing the right thing here.

Comment: Doing the right thing, for the wrong reason?

Comment: yeah exactly, do you have a better idea for the error message?

Comment: I don't know, maybe "Tag synonyms containing numbers can only be created by moderators"?